# change the tag of the exported code

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, python

I want to change the exported tag of

```
#+begin_src python 

..

#+end_src
```

exports to

```
\begin{verbatim}

... 

\end{verbatim}
```

I want it to be export to

```
\begin{python}
\end{python}
```

Anyone has any idea ??
I've only found

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment python
#+begin_example python
#+end_example
```

but then I cant run it ....

Answer (score 0):

Do `C-h v org-latex-listings` (or `C-h v org-latex-src-block-backend` as it was renamed in Org mode 9.6): you probably have it set to `verbatim`.
Try one of the others: `listings` is the simplest to set up, but probably not good-looking enough; `minted` takes some customization (described in the doc string above) but looks pretty good - it's the one that I've used for many years; `engraved` is a recent addition that I have not tried yet, but I'm planning to try it soon.

If you really want a custom environment (like your `python` environment in the question), you can set `org-latex-listings` and `org-latex-custom-lang-environments` appropriately. Again, doing `C-h v org-latex-custom-lang-environments` is the indispensable first step towards enlightenment.

Here's what you would add to your init file to get that:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex
   (setq org-latex-listings "listings")
   (add-to-list 'org-latex-custom-lang-environments '(python "python")))
```

With that, if I export this:

```python
* Code

#+begin_src python :exports both
  print("Hello World!")
#+end_src
```

I get this:

```tex
...
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Code}
\label{sec:org0a74c87}

\begin{python}
print("Hello World!")
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you will need to provide the definition of the `python` environment to LaTeX. I don't have a `python` environment defined, so I cannot process it any further.